# Trying to get a string value in the backend and use it in the front end

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a string value in the backend:

```
string header = "Name of Front page";
```

Then in the asp.net front end side I have:

```
<legend><a href="GenPrefixList.aspx">**I want to use the string "header" in here**</a></legend>
```

I assigned the string to an asp:Label but the html tags like  and legend don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# code:

```
string header = "Name of Front page";
link1.InnerHtml = header;
```

In your aspx page:

```
   <legend><strong><a runat="server" id="link1" href="GenPrefixList.aspx">Sample</a></strong></legend>
```

For making text bold:

**First Option:**

you can use

```
<strong></strong>
```

Eg.

```
<legend><strong><a runat="server" id="link1" href="GenPrefixList.aspx">Sample</a></strong></legend>
```

tag

**Second Option:**
you can use CSS

```
style="font-weight:bold"
```

Eg.:

```
<legend><a runat="server" style="font-weight:bold" id="link1" href="GenPrefixList.aspx">Sample</a></legend>
```

Comment: @IrishChieftain Yes, without that anchor link will not be accessible in C# code.

Comment: I was able to display the text that I want but the formatting (like the <a> links) don't display.

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you explain, what exactly you want ?

Comment: Like the text isn't bold and the text isn't linkable. It's plain text.

Answer (score 3):

You need two things:

1. Public visibility to the value of the string.
2. A call to this visible option from the page.

You can do it in a few different ways, though a public property is considered best practice.

```
public string Header { get { return header; } }
```

At this point, you can output the value:

.NET 4.0 and above:

```
<%:Header%>
```

Before .NET 4.0:

```
<%=Header%>
```

Comment: Declaring the property as `protected` will also do it.

Comment: I get System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead on the webpage. I did double check to make sure the property is filled with the correct value and it is.

Comment: @nhat - Do you have a server side control with the `ID` of `Header`? It would conflict with the one in the code behind.

Comment: I have it set in a div tag: <div runat="server" id="Generate" visible="false"> Is that what you mean?

Comment: @nhat - No. I mean, do you have a control with `runat="server"` and `id="Header"`?

Comment: no runat or id in the tags: <legend><a href="GenPrefixList.aspx"></a> <%:Header%> </legend> Yea I made sure theres no ID with the ID of Header.